# Issue with Travis and pom.xml file

Tags: java, xml, maven, travis-ci

I have a problem with Travis. When I launch the build, the pom.xml file is not found and then the build fails. Can someone tell me where I'm wrong?
This is the repository of my Java project
https://github.com/FilippoCalabrese/tapblockchain
and this is the .travis.yml file

```
language: java
# skip installation step
install: true
script:
- mvn -f pom.xml clean verify
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project structure seems good, can you try with the following file:

```
language: java
script: mvn test
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
```

**EDIT**

It seems that your last build passed.

Comment: yes, with this configuration the build has passed. I did not realize he was still working while I was writing the question. Thanks anyway!